# SQL Server invalid object name with an update statement in SSMS SQL *Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

SSMS for SQL Server 2012 is underlining the table name in an update statement in red and saying that the table does not exist... but it does .. and the update statement works fine ..

I closed SSMS and re-opened it and issue went away.

I'm wondering on what basis SSMS updates it's own idea of what objects exist for the query window syntax highlighting?

I had only created the table on same day but I had done a refresh and table was visible in object explorer tree ..

Not too important .. just close and reopen SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the table was just created and IntelliSense hadn't picked up the metadata yet in your current connection to the SQL Server instance.  To refresh IntelliSense press `CTRL` + `Shift` + `R` in SSMS and the red lines will disappear, as the newly created object is now detected.  To update the cache from the menu in SSMS, go to **Edit** > **IntelliSense** > **Refresh Local Cache** and this will perform the same action.

Comment: Thank you for this tip .. I wondered also .. Is there a way of doing this via menu selections also ?

Comment: Yes there is.  I updated my answer with how to do this.